# How to use StreamingDataFeeder as contrib.learn.Estimator.fit()'s input_fn?

Tags: tensorflow, skflow

I have recently started using `tensorflow.contrib.learn` (skflow) library and really like it. However, I am facing an issue with using `Estimator`, the fit function uses either

1. (`X`, `Y`, and `batch_size`) - the problem with this approach is that it does not support provision for specifying number of epochs and allowing arbitrary source of data.
2. `input_fn` - besides, setting epochs, it gives me much more flexibility on source of training ( which in my case is coming directly from a database).

Now I am aware that I could create input_fn which reads files, however, as I am not interested in dealing with files, the following functions are not useful for me -

- `tf.contrib.learn.read_batch_examples`
- `tf.contrib.learn.read_batch_features`
- `tf.contrib.learn.read_batch_record_features`

Ideally, I would like to use [StreamingDataFeeder](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c99b9bef4cdce8f1724095c77a9620ccf76045be/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/data_feeder.py#L423) as input_fn. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: This discussion is meanwhile moving forward on https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/ZEzEa1TyYuE

Answer (score 0):

`StreamingDataFeeder` is used when you provide iterators as `x` / `y` to `fit`/`predict`/`evaluate` of `Estimator`.

Example:

```
x = (np.array([i]) for i in xrange(10**10)) # use range for python >=3.0
y = (np.array([i + 1]) for i in xrange(10**10))
lr = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(
    feature_columns=[tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column('')])

# only consumes 1000*10 values from iterators.
lr.fit(x, y, steps=1000, batch_size=10)
```

If you want to use `input_fn` for feeding data - you need to use graph operations to read / process data. For example you can create a C++ operation that will produce your data (it can be listening port or reading from database Op) and convert into `Tensor`. Mainly this is good for reading data from files, but other readers can be implemented as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to implement my own reader. But I am lost on where to begin. Can you point me in right direction please?

Comment: Here is the `TFRecordReader` implementation - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/tf_record_reader_op.cc i.e. you need to implement a class that inherits from `ReaderBase` and an Op that you can then call in the input function.