# How to pass data from arbitrary sources (not files) though tensorflow.contrib.learnEstimator.fit input_fn() ?

Tags: python, tensorflow, skflow

The `Estimator.fit()` function takes as argument either

- (`x`, `y`, and `batch_size`) where `x` and `y` could be numpy arrays or iterators.

  **PROS**

  1. Easy to use.
  2. Allows feeding data from arbitrary source as long as problem can be decomposed into `x` and `y`.

  **CONS**

  1. No provision to provide epoch
  2. In case, `x` and `y` are arrays, the data aggregate must be available as opposed to reading on the fly ( say from database)
  3. Whether array or iterator, `x` and `y` can't be dictionaries. Most complex problems cannot be reduced to input matrix and output matrix and may require multiple input features matrices.
- `input_fn` - this is callback function which must return `features` and `target` tensors or dictionary of tensors.

  **PROS**

  1. Allows feeding data from arbitrary source (in theory).
  2. returned features and targets can be dictionary thus allowing to solve complex problems which takes multiple inputs.

  **CONS**

  1. Only found support for reading files using `read_batch_examples()`, `read_batch_features()`, `read_batch_record_features()`, etc.
  2. No support for passing placeholder and feed_fn to allow for arbitrary source of input data which don't require queue.

**Relevant Discussion**

1. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/4696#issuecomment-253632403
2. [How to use StreamingDataFeeder as contrib.learn.Estimator.fit()'s input_fn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855375/how-to-use-streamingdatafeeder-as-contrib-learn-estimator-fits-input-fn)

In discussion in 1., @martinwick suggested using `py_func` to overcome to the CONS for input_fn however, I am still not sure how. Any suggestions, ideas, blueprint welcome.

Comment: Let's track this in Github issue and pull request then. Please see links to the discussions.

Comment: It just got merged.